# API Permissions for Azure API Management and Oauth2

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-api-management

I'm implementing Oauth2 for a simple Azure API Management GET API I have. Here for I followed [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s724GgNUt1g&ab_channel=SriGunnala-TechTalks). My setup works but I don't understand the Application role and API permissions.

So the teacher creates 2 app registrations:

- One for the APIM Resource and creates an app role reader with role Reader
- One for the APIM Client. For the client it adds API permissions and attaches the Reader role with admin consent(3:33) and also Graph permissions with admin consent for `User.Read.All` and `User.ReadWrite.all` (4:09)

Now everything works but I don't understand those permissions, so I removed the role and all permissions (even the default: `User.Read`). Still I can get a valid bearer token and still I can use it for my GET call, so everything is still working.

Do I need an app role and those permissions? If so, which one, what do they mean and how can I keep it as restricted as possible?

Maybe important to note that my client is another application and not a real logged in user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The App Role is custom metadata that would be included in the token and can be used by application for custom authorization policies. For example, an app role for certain functionality within your application like `Admin`.

The other permissions are for Microsoft Graph access (`User.Read` and others). These are required if your application would like to make calls to the Microsoft Graph API, for example, to fetch information about the logged in user or other users in the directory.

To login, you would just require the `openid` scope which is present by default.